# Binary search for sorted multiple items

Tags: algorithm, binary-search

Suppose I have a long sorted list L={1, 2,.., 999, 1000} and a short sorted list S={22, 255, 623, 732, 876}.

In L, I want to search for every element of S. What's most efficient way to do it?

So far the method I came up with is:

```
1. Binary search for 22. Record the lower bound=23
2. Binary search for 876. Record the upper bound=875
3. Binary search for 255 in the range [lower bound=23, upper bound=875].
4. Set lower bound=256, and go on..
```

Is this the most efficient way? Is there any other way that can converge faster than this method?

Thanks!

Comment: Sort the shorter list and for every item in the longer list run a binary search on the shorter one. That is as fast as it gets.

Comment: @BartoszMarcinkowski, that is linear in the length of the longer list, it is certainly not as fast as it gets :)

Comment: You have to read the longer list anyway to decide whether it contains an element or not, unless it is sorted. We don't know if it is sorted.

Comment: From the algo suggested by the OP it appears to me that the long list is already sorted.

Comment: Well, I don't assume what is not explicitly stated :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some suggestion:

1) First, try to find the middle element (623 in the example) of the `sorted short list`, the result is `index`

2) Divide the short list into lower half (which are all elements less than middle element) and upper half (which are all elements greater than middle element).

3) For lower half, we start to search from `0` to `index` of the long list, and for upper half, we start to search from `index + 1` to `n` (n is length of long list)

4) Do step 1 recursively for the two halves.

Comment: Do you mean 2. Divide the *long* list?

Comment: @Blastfurnace I think you misread my answer :), I suggest OP to start to  search from the middle of the short list which narrow down the range when he search for other element in the short list, this is not the typical binary search :) (which actually is nested binary search)

Comment: @Ishamael actually both, the lower half elements of the short list need to be searched in the lower half of the long list (from 0 to `index`, with `index` is the result of binary search for the middle element)

Comment: @PhamTrung Thanks! Sounds a lot of programming but worth the case since my lists are huge.

Comment: @PhamTrung I am not good at the complexity theory, but do you think your alg is approximately O(logS*logL)? Just interested..:)

Comment: I came up with `O(S log(L/S))` time complexity. The complexity is determined by `log L + 2 log (L/2) + 4 log (L/4) + ...`. First `log L` is the initial middle element binary search. Second `log (L/2)` is the lower and upper half search. We can approximate this to `log L + log(L/2) + log (L/3) + log(L/4) + ...`, which is technically an incorrect approximation, but should be close enough. From the approximation, we get `O(log(L^S/S!)) = O(S log(L/S))`.

Answer (score 1):

Your idea to keep track of the bounds and to reduce the search range is good. Your approach of looking up entries alternately from the left and right end is as good as moving through the small array from left to right and just adjusting the lower bound. (Unless you know something on the distribution of the keys in S.)

I think you should work recursively on the small array and cut in in half on every recursion, binary-search style. Look up `623` in array `L` and find index `k`. Next recurse to the left subarray and look up the entries in `{22, 255}` in `L[0...k]`. Then recurse to the right and look up entries `{723, 876}` in `L[k + 1...|L|]`.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mentioned in one of the comments that your lists are huge, if your shorter list has length comparable to the lenght of the longer list, you can just set two pointers at the beginning of both lists, and at each step move one that points to the smaller element to the right. Whenever both pointers point at equal values, you found a match. This will be `O(s + l)`, which will be faster than naive `O(s log l)` if `s` is close to `l` (`s` is the length of the shorter list, `l` is the length of the longer list).

Comment: Thanks:) Unfortunately my short list has about 20K and the longer one has about 10M..